# Error connecting to CKAN via ckanapi using Airflow

Tags: airflow

Error connecting to CKAN via ckanapi using Airflow
Hello, I am using Airflow to upload datasets to CKAN. For the connection to CKAN I use ckanapi and it works correctly if I run locally from my virtualenv. However, when I run the same function from the Airflow DAG, the process waits for the connection to CKAN to be resolved and never finishes resolving. Any ideas?

```
ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN(urlckan,session=session, apikey=Authorization, user_agent='myuseragent')
```

I am using Python 3.11, ckanapi 4.7 and running Airflow into virtualenv project in local without Docker

I have tried with pythonoperator only